# Why is this identity about commutators of Lie derivatives true?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, na.numerical-analysis

I am reading the paper "On splitting methods for Schrödinger-Poisson and cubic nonlinear Schrödinger equations" by Lubich. On page 2147 the author claims

$$[T,V](\psi) = T'(\psi) V(\psi) - V'(\psi) T(\psi) $$

where $T(\psi) = i\Delta \psi$ and $V(\psi) = -i\tilde{V}[\psi]\psi$ with $\tilde{V}([\psi])= \Delta^{-1} |\psi|^2$ where $\psi$ is a complex-valued $H^2$-function on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (so that $\Delta\psi$ is well-defined). It is then claimed that
$$
\begin{split}
 T'(\psi) V(\psi) - V'(\psi) T(\psi) = &\; i\Delta(-i\Delta^{-1}(\psi\bar{\psi}) \psi) + i\Delta^{-1}(-i\Delta \psi \bar{\psi})\psi \\
&\;+ i\Delta^{-1}(\psi  \overline{i\Delta\psi}) + i\Delta^{-1}(\psi\bar{\psi})i\Delta \psi  
\end{split}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
So the derivative in $T'(\psi)$ is probably just some sort of formal derivative with respect to $\psi$ but what would $(i\Delta \psi)'$ be then? The first term in $(1)$ is cleary coming from $T'(\psi)V(\psi)$ but it doesn't make sense to me from the definition of $T'(\psi)$. It would make sense as $T(V(\psi))$, though. So is $T'(\psi)=T(\psi)$ then?

The other terms are confusing as well. Naively, we would have
$$(\tilde{V}[\psi]\psi)' = \tilde{V}[\psi]'\psi + \tilde{V}[\psi]$$
which, again, doesn't fit with what we have in \eqref{1}.

More formal than above, $T$ and $V$ are vector fields and their and the corresponding differential equation is 
$$\partial_t \psi = T(\psi) + V(\psi)$$
In that sense the commutator is the Lie bracket of vector fields.

Maybe someone can give me some clarification?

Comment: $T$ is a linear operator so it makes sense that its derivative is itself.  I haven't sorted through the other terms yet.

Comment: what is $\Delta$? (minus) Laplacian?

Comment: Yes, the standard Laplacian